# How do I call a method from fragment to class?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a fragment and I want to call to a method which is in a AppConfig.class. But when I run the application there was a error came as `" Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences.edit()' on a null object reference"`. How do I solve this error?

Here is my code in AppConfig.class

```
 public void updateUserLoginStatus(boolean status){

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(context.getString(R.string.pref_is_user_login),status);
    editor.apply();

}
```

Here is my code in Fragment

```
appConfig.updateUserLoginStatus(false);
```

Comment: sharedPreferences is null.

Comment: Can you share the Share Preference initialization?

Comment: use `editor.commit();` instead  `editor.apply();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access Shared Preference as default file name from all activities/fragment then consider to use

> getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)

> Gets a SharedPreferences instance that points to the default file that is used by the preference framework in the given context.

So in `AppConfig` class you can implement a void where you can pass `Context` from different Activities to get `getDefaultSharedPreferences` .

```
private static Context context;
static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public static void init(Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

}
```

Before call `updateUserLoginStatus` , you have to call `AppConfig.init()` .

From Activity -

```
     AppConfig.init(this);

    AppConfig appConfig = new AppConfig();
    appConfig.updateUserLoginStatus(false);
```

From Fragment -

```
     AppConfig.init(getContext());
     AppConfig appConfig = new AppConfig();
     appConfig.updateUserLoginStatus(false);
```

Comment: You may accept the answer by clicking on check mark ✓

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Appconfig object in your calling Activity/fragment.

Example -

Appconfig appconfig = new Appconfig ();
appconfig.updateUserLoginStatus(false);

Null pointer exception shows that, you have just declared a global variable in your class for appConfig but not initialised it.